# View not attached to window manager: Although I have preventive code

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I keep getting this error but  I am not sure why

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:587)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:324)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:151)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:328)
        at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:119)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:313)
```

And it happens in this code

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(!isFinishing() && dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();  <-------- HERE IT HAPPENS
        }
   }
```

Any idea why? I am making sure the activity is not finishing and the dialog is showing before dismissal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally happens when the `Activity` might have finished or in pause state before the `AsyncTask` is complete. `onPause` of the `Activity` set the dialog to null or  dismiss it

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if(!isPaused && dialog.isShowing()){
        dialog.dismiss();  <-------- HERE IT HAPPENS
    }
}
boolean isPaused;
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isPaused = true;
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isPaused = false;
    if(dialog.isShowing() && (asyncFinishedCheck)){
        //Dismiss code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: but I am not dismissing it when it isFinishing or dialog is not showing as I showed on the code

Comment: but still activity can go onPause sate, isFinishing will only return true when the activity is about to get finished(killed). Not when the activity is going to onPause state

Comment: So when the activity resumes, does it dismiss the dialog by default?

Comment: Never that you need to write the code, if the AsyncTask is finished and if still the dialog is shoeing dismiss it. See the edited code.

Comment: Perfect thanks. It is surprising that such a very common task has to be so convoluted!.

Comment: It will be always better to show a loader view instead of a dialog. So that we won't be blocking the user from any thing. If you are loading some data for a Listview show the loader inside that list view.